# Run Time Binding in java

Tags: java

In Java objects are created at run time, so over rided methods can only bind at run time. But by going though a program, I think compiler can often easily find which method should bind to what method call. Why this method binding postponed to run time even in simple cases?

Comment: What happens when I swap the `class` implementation at runtime? Don't forget, Java is _dynamic_ at runtime.

Comment: Over-*ridden* methods are bound at runtime. Overloaded methods are bound at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you read that overloaded methods are bound at run time. The method signatures are chosen at compile time.